# Copy/paste texts to Tor

Tags: help

If I have a text in ""LibreOffice Writer"" or ""Word"", or if I have a text in an email or at some website that I wrote or accessed in clearnet; can I just copy/paste that text from my computer/clearnet to the Tor browser without revealing my identity?

Comment: Sometimes, sometimes not. It depends.

Comment: Cheers. Can you be a bit more specific though. When, when not? (And to be a bot more specific about my question: Original text would be deleted afterwards)